# How to hide a external script when browser window resizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have an external script(a chatterbox one) hosted on another website. It's positioned to the right of my list with float:right. The problem I have is that when the browser window resizes, it overflows onto the list. I have tried overflow:hidden; but that doesn't work.[This is what happens when the browser window overflows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jykdu.png)
[This is how it normally looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUCbU.png)

Comment: It is difficult to help you without having your HMTL and CSS code, however, try to set `width` for both containers in percentage.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You say "hide a script," but that's not a meaningful thing. Do you mean you want to hide an HTML element created by a script?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS media query, like this:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
    #chat-box {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This can be read as:

If the screen is less than 600px wide, hide the element with the id chat-box.

Place this in a **style** tag or in a **.css** file.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS important, like this:

```
overflow: hidden !important;
```